# Custom Shopping Cart Sitecore XP

Tags: sitecore-commerce

TBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBDTBD

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store your products data into a `custom databse` and retrive them when user add them to shopping cart using simply Experience Platform (XP) only.

The Sitecore E-Commerce module is `not mandatory` for this functionality, as you can implement custom shopping cart functionality using the normal `ASP.Net MVC/core`  application and a custom database.

Similarly, you can create a custom controller to handle the shopping cart page, which would retrieve the products from the custom database and display them on the page using `EntityFramework` instead of Sitecore API.

And for implementaion using custom database, suggest you can follow the tutorial at [Use a custom SQL provider to store form data](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/web-forms-for-marketers/use-a-custom-sql-provider-to-store-form-data.html) ,then you can write `your own code logic` to implement the functionality.

While it is strongly `recommened` to integrate it with antoher Sitecore product which is called `Sitecore Experience Commerce (XC)`,which has `built-in functionality` for managing products, carts, checkouts, and other e-commerce features.

And furthermore, there is a powerful `SAAS product` in Sitecore called [OrderCloud](https://www.sitecore.com/products/ordercloud).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to purchase an eCommerce service to implement cart/checkout functionalities.

All you need is a database, that too, you can get for free (trial, community edition etc...)

*Create your tables carefully though.*
Based on the structure of your tables, your site functionality will be impacted.
I would separate out cart, line items, shipping, billing tables for easier management.

You can take advantage of Session/Cookies to store relevant information along with cart id.

I have personally done a similar implementation in the past where I created an event management website for private community use.

Unfortunately, it is private so I cannot share the codebase. But, if you DM me, I can provide credentials so you can surf around.